# IF condition is evaluated wrong for string comparison

Tags: string, abap

When you type the zodiac sign in the parameter, an example is "Leo" or "LEO", the output should appear as "This user is a LEO" but when I do it only shows me the word "INVALID".

Can someone help me so that when I try to type a specific word it will appear as what the conditions states?

This is my code:

```
REPORT Z_006_EXER3.
PARAMETERS zodiac(10) TYPE C.
DATA today type d.
today = sy-datum.

WRITE:/ 'Your horoscope as of today', sy-datum.
if zodiac = 'Capricorn''CAPRICORN'.
  write:/ 'The user is a capricorn'.
elseif zodiac = 'Aquarius''AQUARIUS'.
  write:/ 'The user is an Aquarius'.
elseif zodiac = 'Pisces''PISCES'.
  write:/ 'The user is a PISCES'.
elseif zodiac = 'Aries''ARIES'.
  write:/ 'The user is an ARIES'.
elseif zodiac = 'Taurus''TAURUS'.
  write:/ 'The user is a TAURUS'.
elseif zodiac = 'Gemini''GEMINI'.
  write:/ 'The user is a GEMINI'.
elseif zodiac = 'Cancer''CANCER'.
  write:/ 'The user is a CANCER'.
elseif zodiac = 'Leo''LEO'.
  write:/ 'The user is a LEO'.
elseif zodiac = 'Virgo''VIRGO'.
  write:/ 'The user is a VIRGO'.
elseif zodiac = 'Libra''LIBRA'.
  write:/ 'The user is a LIBRA'.
elseif zodiac = 'Scorpio''SCORPIO'.
  write:/ 'The user is a SCORPPIO'.
elseif zodiac = 'Sagittarius''SAGITTARIUS'.
  write:/ 'The user is a SAGITTARIUS'.
else.
  write:/ 'Invalid'.
endif.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With this line of code:

```
elseif zodiac = 'Leo''LEO'.
```

you are testing if the variable `zodiac` equals the two concatenated words "`Leo'LEO`" with one single quote between them. You are not testing "Leo" or "LEO".

Instead, you should do, as Greg said:

```
elseif zodiac = 'Leo' OR zodiac = 'LEO'.
```

If you want to know all possible syntaxes, read the official [ABAP documentation about Logical Expressions](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_latest_index_htm/latest/en-US/index.htm?file=abenlogexp.htm) (NOT, OR, AND, EQUIV, etc.)

I can add a few things about your specific algorithm:

- As you are evaluating the same variable in your IF...ELSEIF chain, you may use the [CASE...WHEN construct](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_latest_index_htm/latest/en-US/index.htm?file=abapcase.htm) or the Constructor Operator [`SWITCH`](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_latest_index_htm/latest/en-US/index.htm?file=abenconditional_expression_switch.htm).
- As I guess that you are trying to ignore the letter case, you may simplify your code by changing the input to upper case with either [`to_upper`](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_latest_index_htm/latest/en-US/index.htm?file=abencase_functions.htm) or the old [`TRANSLATE...TO UPPER CASE`](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_latest_index_htm/latest/en-US/index.htm?file=abaptranslate.htm), and then comparing it with only the word in upper case.
- Your evaluation may also be condensed into a shorter form by using any of the two Constructor Operators [`SWITCH`](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_latest_index_htm/latest/en-US/index.htm?file=abenconditional_expression_switch.htm) or [`COND`](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_latest_index_htm/latest/en-US/index.htm?file=abenconditional_expression_cond.htm).
- If you repeat the text "The user is", you may define it once in a variable and concatenate it afterwards, for instance by using a [String Template](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_latest_index_htm/latest/en-US/index.htm?file=abenstring_templates.htm) (`|...{ ... }...|`).

Example of final code with ABAP version >= 7.40:

```
DATA(zodiac_input_evaluation) = SWITCH string( to_upper( zodiac ) 
    LET intro = `The user is` IN
    WHEN 'CAPRICORN'   THEN |{ intro } a capricorn|
    WHEN 'AQUARIUS'    THEN |{ intro } an Aquarius|
    WHEN 'PISCES'      THEN |{ intro } a PISCES|
    WHEN 'ARIES'       THEN |{ intro } an ARIES|
    WHEN 'TAURUS'      THEN |{ intro } a TAURUS|
    WHEN 'GEMINI'      THEN |{ intro } a GEMINI|
    WHEN 'CANCER'      THEN |{ intro } a CANCER|
    WHEN 'LEO'         THEN |{ intro } a LEO|
    WHEN 'VIRGO'       THEN |{ intro } a VIRGO|
    WHEN 'LIBRA'       THEN |{ intro } a LIBRA|
    WHEN 'SCORPIO'     THEN |{ intro } a SCORPPIO|
    WHEN 'SAGITTARIUS' THEN |{ intro } a SAGITTARIUS|
    ELSE 'Invalid' ).
WRITE : / zodiac_input_evaluation.
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead:
`if zodiac = 'Capricorn''CAPRICORN'`
You should have:
`if zodiac = 'Capricorn' or zodiac = 'CAPRICORN'`